# USB Card Swipe input (ID cards) connected to Android Tablet

Tags: android

I have a question about connecting a card scanner (ex: http://www.magtek.com/v2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/magnesafe-mini.asp) over USB to an Android tablet (2.2) and allowing for scanning of an Id card. The scanner emulates a keypad entry and should send back a text string to the app. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so any pointers to some reference code?

Thanks in advance.